# Handling non-utf8 characters in csv in Python 3 vs Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, unicode

I have the following code which reads csv files (some containing non-UTF8 characters). It works well in Python 2.7.x:

```
    encodings = {'ukprocessed.csv': 'utf8',
                 'usprocessed.csv': 'utf8',
                 'uyprocessed.csv': 'latin1',
                 'arprocessed.csv': 'latin1'}

    with codecs.open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            row = [x.decode(encodings[filename]).encode('utf8') for x in row]
```

However, in Python 3.4.x the tests fail with a variety of errors:

- AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
- UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 1078: ordinal not in range(128)
  etc...

I have played around with specifying 'encoding=' in the file open, opening as bytes with 'rb' and a number of other things but I can't find a solution which works in both Python 2 and 3.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Narrowly addressing the cause of your error:

In Py3, the `x` values in each `row` are `str` (similar to Py2 `unicode`). In Py2, `str` and `unicode` were too flexible, because `str` was both a text and binary data type; it supported `encode`, sort of, by assuming the `str` was ASCII, decoding it, then reencoding as the chosen encoding (which for ASCII compatible codecs was pointless, since it would error when non-ASCII was encountered). And for symmetry, a similarly error prone and pointless `decode` of `unicode` types was allowed; it would `encode` to ASCII (erroring if the `unicode` contained non-ASCII), then `decode` in the requested codec. This was a source of all sorts of misunderstandings, errors, etc.

In Python 3, they split the types up better:

1. `str` is *the* text type, and only has an `encode` method (to convert from logical characters to a specific binary encoding of said characters)
2. `bytes` (and other `bytes`-like types) represent binary data, and only have a `decode` method (to convert from a specific binary encoding to logical characters)

---

### Solving your problem in a portable way:

Your code requires that "pure text" types support `decode` (binary->text), and as I noted, Py2 allows this in a limited sense, even though it's usually dumb. Py3 doesn't; `decode`-ing logical text to logical text is nonsensical, and to avoid silent misbehavior, Py3 doesn't provide the invalid methods (Py2 will work depending on the content of the `unicode` object, then fail when it's wrong; you'll think your code is non-English friendly, then it breaks if you actually use it with non-English text).

Writing `csv` code that must handle non-ASCII types isn't trivial if you need full portability. Here's the problem:

1. In Python 2, you must work with `str` (bytes-oriented) encoded as some encoding that doesn't include embedded `NUL`s, not `unicode`. *Note:* `unicode` happens to work by coincidence if it contains only text in the encoding returned by `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, because `csv` silently encodes it using the value, usually `ascii`, configured on startup by the `site` module using `sys.setdefaultencoding`; `site` deletes `sys.setdefaultencoding` after calling it, you're not supposed to tweak it yourself; it breaks when the input has anything that doesn't fit the locale encoding during `csv`'s forcible conversion from `unicode` back to `str`. It's not just a matter of your system locale either; on my system, using `LANG=en_US.latin-1` or `LANG=en_US.utf-8`, Python is still returning `'ascii'` as my `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.
2. In Python 3, you must work with `str` (text-oriented, equivalent to Py2's `unicode`)

Normally, for non-`csv` related cases, I'd recommend using `io.open` to get full compatibility between Py2.7 and Py3.x (and better performance/compatibility than `codecs.open`) with a purely text-based type. But `io.open` (and `codecs.open` for that matter) in text mode returns `unicode` on Py2 (can't be used with `csv` unless it's representable in the default encoding, so you'll think it works until you feed it something the default encoding can't handle), and `str` in Py3 (fine); in binary mode, it returns `str` on Py2 (fine if no embedded `NUL`s, though it's not decoding for you, so you'd need to both decode from `str` to `unicode`, then encode back from `unicode` to `utf-8` `str`) and `bytes` in Py3 (would need to be decoded to `str`). It's ugly.

The best solution I can give is to use `io.open`, but add a version dependent wrappers around the iterators produced at specific steps to ensure the output from the iterator is in the appropriate form for the given Python version (`utf-8` encoded `str` in Py2, `str` in Py3), giving you consistent behavior (and limiting the version checks to being performed a fixed number of times per file, not once per line):

```
import io
import sys

encodings = {'ukprocessed.csv': 'utf8',
             'usprocessed.csv': 'utf8',
             'uyprocessed.csv': 'latin1',
             'arprocessed.csv': 'latin1'}

# io.open in text mode will return unicode on Py2, str on Py3, decoded appropriately
# newline='' prevents it from doing line ending conversions (which are csv's
# responsibility)
with io.open(filepath, encoding=encodings[filepath], newline='') as csvdata:
    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        # Lazily convert lines from unicode to utf-8 encoded str
        csvdata = (line.encode('utf-8') for line in csvdata)
    reader = csv.reader(csvdata)
    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        # Decode row values to unicode on Py2; they're already str in Py3
        reader = ([x.decode('utf-8') for x in row] for row in reader)
    for row in reader:
        # operate on row containing native text types as values that can
        # represent whole Unicode range (unicode on Py2, str on Py3)
        ...
```

Comment: Fantastic answer - very useful description and worked in both Python 2&3. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike91: it is error-prone to sprinkle your code with `.encode()`/`.decode()` everywhere. If you need  a single source Python 2/3 compatible code then work with Unicode and hide the difference behind an interface such as [`unicodecsv`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33678737/4279)

Comment: @jfs: That's why I used generator expressions to limit the `encode` and `decode` usage to exactly two lines of preprocessing separated from the code that works with the rows; it avoids constant version checks (the version check is performed a fixed number of times, not once per row or per cell), and it's done outside the main loop (so the main loop can work with a known Unicode-friendly text type unconditionally). While `unicodecsv` does work, it's not always possible to install 3rd party libraries; a solution that only requires a fixed 4 lines (which can be factored out) for compat isn't bad.

Comment: After all, you could factor it out for reuse as just `if sys.version_info[0] == 2: unicodecsvreader = csv.reader`, `else:` `def unicodecsvreader(f, *args, **kwargs): return ([x.decode('utf-8') for x in row] for row in csv.reader((line.encode('utf-8') for line in f), *args, **kwargs))` (ideally breaking it up into a couple line in real code that isn't SO comment format constrained), and now your usage for all versions is the same, and obvious.

Answer (score 4):

`csv` isn't very portable between Python 2 and 3, but [`unicodecsv`](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import unicodecsv

encodings = {'ukprocessed.csv': 'utf8',
             'usprocessed.csv': 'utf8',
             'uyprocessed.csv': 'latin1',
             'arprocessed.csv': 'latin1'}

for filepath,enc in encodings.items():
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = unicodecsv.reader(csvfile,encoding=enc)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

This was tested on Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.5.  It is important to open in `rb` mode because `unicodecsv` works with byte strings similar to Python 2.7's `csv` module.  Python 3.X's `csv` module works with Unicode strings directly.

Answer (score 1):

The codecs.open wrapper already provides you with decoding. Give this a try:

```
with codecs.open(filepath, 'r', encoding = encodings[filename]) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            #do what you need
```

Comment: This will break the instant an input file contains Unicode that cannot be represented in the encoding returned by `sys.getdefaultencoding()`; Py2 `csv` is silently converting `unicode` input (the type `codecs.open` yields) to `str` using that encoding, and that encoding is usually `ascii` (even if it's something else, that just means you silently accept input that can be represented in that encoding, then break when an input contains a value that can't be). If you're writing code targeting Py2 and Py3, this is wrong; if it's targetting Py3 only, using `codecs` is poor form.